# Subtracting a textbox from a cell in the database

Tags: c#

I have a button which adds products to the invoice, I want it to delete products off the database as well, how can I edit this query so it deletes from the database?

I think my error is because of the way I am converting cmbQuantity.Text, can someone help me with a fix?

```
SqlCommand inventorycontrol = new SqlCommand("Update Product SET quantityAvailable=quantityAvailabe - '" + Convert.ToInt32(cmbQuantity.Text) + "' WHERE productName='" + cmbProdName.Text + "'", con);
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? An exception? No updates? What platform, what is your table layout? How and when do you execute this command?

Comment: Oh my goodness, SQL injection. I'm assuming cmbProdName is a textbox. I'll wipe your DB now: `1' -- DROP TABLE Product;` Always sanitize your inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the error message, it's hard to guess.

But at first sight, you have a typo here :  `quantityAvailable=quantityAvailabe -` should be `quantityAvailable=quantityAvailab**l**e -`.

Moreover, you must not quote the integer part, so `'" + quantityToRemove  + "'` becomes `" + quantityToRemove  + "`. But the best is to use parametrization, which will simplify your code. See [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Try to separate access to your UI and building your SQL:

```
int quantityToRemove = Convert.ToInt32(cmbQuantity.Text);
string productName = cmbProdName.Text;

string sqlUpdate = @"UPDATE Product 
                     SET quantityAvailable = quantityAvailable - @quantityToRemove
                     WHERE productName= @productName";
SqlCommand inventorycontrol = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdate, con);
inventorycontrol .Parameters.AddWithValue("quantityToRemove", quantityToRemove);
inventorycontrol .Parameters.AddWithValue("productName", productName);
```

Comment: Why not `int.TryParse()`

Comment: I just cut and paste the given code. Using parametrize query is the number one problem in this code. Handling error case on input comes after, but I think OP needs one advice at a time :)

Comment: Thanks alot :) it works, I agree there is a long way from this code being ever used, but i just started c#, so I wasn't looking into much of the issues like injections, Thanks for the feedback as well

Comment: I'm genuinely confused. What does the OP's query, SQL injection, question redaction, this answer, and the question title have to do with ^*anything*? "Subtracting a textbox from a cell in the database", "I have a button which adds products to the invoice, I want it to delete products off the database as well", and then we have a query which looks like a stock movement? :-O

Comment: well basically the form adds products to an invoice, I got that part working, but it needed to minus the products from inventory as soon as it is added to invoice, this query helps to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you have not specify the error, but there may be chances of getting error in your code. that i will clarify you.

1. When it failed to convert the `cmbQuantity.Text` to int, you need not to pass an integer within double quotes :- Here my suggested answer will help you to handle this error by showing error message if the quantity is invalid.
2. The query you are using opens a wide range to [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). I suggest you to use  parameterized query to avoid injection, As a whole you can use like the following:

   ```
    int quantity;
       if (int.TryParse(cmbQuantity.Text, out quantity))
       {
           SqlCommand inventorycontrol = new SqlCommand("Update Product SET quantityAvailable=quantityAvailabe - @Quantity WHERE productName=@prodName", con);
           inventorycontrol.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity",quantity);
           inventorycontrol.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", cmbProdName.Text);
           //Execue command here
       }
       else
       {
           // show message invalid quantity
       }
   ```

Comment: I think you want to replace `Convert.ToInt32()` with `quantity`.